# Understanding a batch script for improvisation

Tags: batch-file

I thrive on angular, html and css so basically I'm on UI but I've been asked to look into a batch script and improvise it as a part of a proof of concept
Below is the script, I've tried as much as I could to understand by going through multiple links but I'm finding it really hard to connect the dots from start to finish

It will be a great help if someone could explain me this script

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in ("%WORKSPACE%\Tests\*.sql") do (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in ("%%~nxf") do (
        SET _schema=%%a
        IF "!_schema:~0,4!"=="test" (
            IF NOT "!_schema:~0,4!"=="test " (
                SQLCMD -S "%DBSERVER%" -E -d "%DBNAME%" -Q "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = '!_schema!') EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass @ClassName = N'!_schema!'"
                )
            )
        )
    SQLCMD -S "%DBSERVER%" -E -d "%DBNAME%" -i "%%f"
)
```

Comment: It is very poor code, which enumerates all non hidden SQL files in the `%WORKSPACE%\Tests` directory, and for any whose name does not begin with a semicolon, runs `SQLCMD -S "%DBSERVER%" -E -d "%DBNAME%" -i "%WORKSPACE%\Tests\FILENAME.sql"`. Additionally if the first four non period characters are `test` and those are not followed immediately by a space character, it will first run `SQLCMD -S "%DBSERVER%" -E -d "%DBNAME%" -Q "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'FILENAMEUPTOFIRSTNONLEADINGPERIOD') EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass @ClassName = N'FILENAMEUPTOFIRSTNONLEADINGPERIOD'"`.

Comment: @Compo : I'd suggest `NOT "!_schema:~0,4!"=="test " (` will **ALWAYS** be true. (4 chars vs 5)

Comment: @Magoo, I said it's very poor code. I've had to kind of make some assumptions as to the intention, although as you say, four characters will never match five, so I could have missed the part about the space character out, and just say, "Additionally if the first four non period characters are `test`, it will first run `SQLCMD -S "%DBSERVER%" -E -d "%DBNAME%" -Q "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'FILENAMEUPTOFIRSTNONLEADINGPERIOD') EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass @ClassName = N'FILENAMEUPTOFIRSTNONLEADINGPERIOD'"`". I'd also assume that using a period as a delimiter wasn't needed!